# Windows tool to delete content from several different folders on click?

Tags: windows-7-x64, directory

I have several folders spread all across my disk and I have to manually delete the content multiple times a day (its some cache thing). Is there a nice tool where I can specify the folders and delete their content at once with either a click or shortcut or something? The folders themselves have to stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always write a batch script to do this for you.

Create a file, call it 'wipefolders.bat'

Then write something like this inside

```
cd <drive>:
cd root\path\of\folders

cd foldera
del *.*
cd ..

cd folderb
del *.*

etc...
```

Then just create a shortcut to this link.